# international student tax deduction while trading

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, penny-stocks

I am an international student in US. I just want to explore the world of stock market and trading. I am doing it by "Robinhood". I know i need to pay taxes at the end. But I am not trading very high value stocks.

So, my question is what is the limit below which I don't have to pay taxes while trading. I just invested $10. Do I have to pay taxes for this too? what are the slabs?

I am also having an assistantship. So is holding two sources of income legitimate?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> So, my question is what is the limit below which I don't have to pay taxes while trading. I just invested $10. Do I have to pay taxes for this too? what are the slabs?

Any income is subject to tax. That said, investing $10 will probably not generate much of income, even at the discount brokers most of it will be wasted on commissions...

> I am also having an assistantship. So is holding two sources of income legitimate? Thanks

You can have as many sources of income as you want. **Working** is what is restricted when you're on a student visa. As long as you don't open a business as a day trader or start working for someone trading stocks - you're fine.